# Issue calling a Python script in PHP that imports BeautifulSoup4

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup

I have a PHP file which calls a Python script to then return the value that outputs to PHP.

```
$price = system("/usr/local/bin/python3 /full/path/script.py", $retval);
```

For testing purposes due to this error, I commented everything out of the Python script except for printing a string to be returned. If I have it like this, it returns that string, but if I uncomment the line

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

then it fails. The other imports that I have, which are for sys and requests, work without any issue but when I have BeautifulSoup imported then nothing is returned and I get a $retval of 1. Running the full Python script from command line works perfectly but when I do it with PHP the command fails.

What would be keeping this from working properly in PHP but it works fine when done in the command line? I have ensured that bs4 is installed with pip but I knew that anyway since it works fine from the command line.

Comment: In a command line python shell, try `import bs4;print(bs4.__file__)`. Is that path in a system path? Its possible bs4 is a local install.

Comment: You may get more information by putting the import in a try/except clause. On failure, `import traceback;import sys;traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)` . With any luck you can read the error message that normally goes out `stderr` and get more information.

Comment: @tdelaney when I run the command from your first message I get `/u/bcs2363/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py` so does this mean its a local install? I'm running this on a university linux machine so I'm hoping this isn't an issue with them not letting install it without it only being local

Comment: That looks like a local install to me. You could `import site;site.getsitepackages()` to see the standard directories on your machine. The question is which user the web service is running under. Maybe they will install bs4 globally and if they say no, then see if they will do it for the user where php runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This was the only command working for me once.
Be sure that the python path is correct. On my mashine i installed anaconda package, so the path is different. Remember that if you are running php on your apache server, you call the command as the apache "www-data" user and not as your logged on user.

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/python3 /full/path/script.py 2>&1', $out);
```